# stop the Flash from caching BUT not stop a cookie from being cached

Tags: php, html, flash

I have problem with flash

"Game.swf" are not able to cache the games but they are meant to cache the cookies.
What happens is if I dont clear my cache I get an old version of the game and then see old issues.

I need to stop the games from caching BUT not stop a cookie from being cached.

I also used meta tag in html

```
     <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
     <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
     <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
```

any solution.

**CODE Here**

```
<div class="obj">
        <script language="javascript">
      if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
      } else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        'width', '900',
        'height', '675',
        'src', 'game',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'true',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'showall',
        'wmode', 'window',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'game',
        'bgcolor', '#000000',
        'name', 'game',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','always',
        'movie', 'game',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
       }
    </script>
    <noscript>
 <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="900" height="675" id="game" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="game.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />    
<embed src="game.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="900" height="675" name="game" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
  </object>
   </noscript>
        </div>
```

Comment: We need the bit of code that creates the cookie.

Comment: @MichalM sorry i have not code of swf.

Comment: None of the cache control headers you pasted affect cookies in normal situations. If the cookie disappears it is very likely it has a short expiration date or session expiration date (expires when you close browser window).

Comment: No, cache and cookies are not related.

Comment: when the game is updated and the user doesn't see it because the old version is cached.